# Requested operation is not valid: domain is not running

Tags: virtual-machines

My virsh list --all

```
Id   Name                    State
----------------------------------------
 -    k3s-1-192.168.122.213   shut off
 -    k3s-2-192.168.122.214   shut off
 -    k3s-3-192.168.122.215   shut off
```

I tried reboot

```
virsh reboot k3s-1-192.168.122.213
error: Failed to reboot domain 'k3s-1-192.168.122.213'
error: Requested operation is not valid: domain is not running
```

How to reboot?

Comment: Since the machine is not running, you're probably looking for `virsh start`.

Comment: regardless which hypervisor you use, a non powered on machine can't be restarted ;)

Comment: @djdomi fixed with ansible-playbook playbook_terraform_kvm.yml,powered the machines.

Comment: please share the output of your solution as an answer and accept it 24h later on